# Uncaught TypeError: sqlsrv_fetch_array() error since upgrade to PHP8.1

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv, php-8.1

today i upgraded to php8.1 and since then i have the following problem. I run the following query:

```
$xx1 = sqlsrv_query($db, "SELECT * FROM xx WHERE xx = ".$xy." ORDER BY xx;", array(), array("QueryTimeout" => 30));
```

then i want to loop through the array and output the data:

```
while($xx = sqlsrv_fetch_array($xx1, 2)){
   do something
 }
```

this had always worked so far (php7.2). Since the upgrade, this unfortunately only works sometimes. Sometimes it runs without problems and sometimes I get the following error in the logs:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: sqlsrv_fetch_array(): Argument #1 ($stmt) must be of type resource, bool given in /var/www/xxx.php:30\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/xxx.php(30): sqlsrv_fetch_array()\n#1 {main}\n thrown in /var/www/xxx.php on line 30
```

On average I get the error once per 5 times executing.

as requestet the full code:

```
$chatID = $obj['chatID'];

$messages1 = sqlsrv_query($db, "SELECT * FROM dbo.Messages WHERE ChatID = ".$chatID." ORDER BY Date;", array(), array("QueryTimeout" => 30));
if( $messages1 === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            console_error("SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']);
            console_error("code: ".$error[ 'code']);
            console_error("message: ".$error[ 'message']);
        }
    }
}
$messagesarray = array();

while($messages = sqlsrv_fetch_array($messages1, 2)){
      array_push($messagesarray, array(
        "messages" =>  $messages['Message'],
        "Date" => $messages['Date']->format('d.m. H:i'),
      );
}
```

Comment: `sqlsrv_query()` might return false, and you need to check for that condition.

Comment: `WHERE xx = ".$xy."` look like you're injecting your parameter, not parametrising it,

Comment: @Alex I have already done that. The statement seems to work and no error is issued.

Comment: The error you're getting conflicts with that statement. Post the rest of the code.

Comment: @AlexHowansky the code is now in the post

Comment: I don't see any check for the possibility of sqlsrv_query() returning false.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I had temporarily checked as follows:
if( $messages1 === false ) {
    if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            console_error("SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']);
            console_error("code: ".$error[ 'code']);
            console_error("message: ".$error[ 'message']);
        }
    }
}

Comment: Why temporarily? This should be done every time. Also note you're not terminating the script on error, you're just dumping the message and then attempting to continue anyway.

Comment: that is quite correct. But no error is output.

Comment: You can't get the error message you're getting unless `$messages1` is false.